# What is the definition of "hangry"?

Tags: meaning

Is *hangry* a real word? According to [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hangry) it means *to be angry as a result of being hungry*, but it seems far-fetched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's in a dictionary, especially one with professional full-time editors, the chances are it's a real word. Of these kind of dictionaries, I can only find it in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hangry), and their webpage notes it's "humorous" and also added from a recent suggestion:

> Comment byCollins Dictionary (Admin) on 7 Sep 2012
>   'hangry' definition based on an original suggestion by Jude made on 2012-06-29.

Collins also say:

> Word Frequency: No usage level data available

The word is in [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hangry) and first defined in [2003](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hangry&defid=176630). Their [most popular definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Hangry&defid=1000659) was an Urban Word of the Day with over 10,000 upvotes so it must be fairly well known slang.

You can find it used on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/search/hangry), although often with an explanation it means hungry and angry.

The earliest *hangry* I found with this definition in Usenet is in rec.games.trivia from [1996](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/rec.games.trivia/7fEFyofJzjU):

> [Hangry], although not often used in current English, describes the person who is so hungry he becomes angry. Tell your callers this and they probably won't call back 
>   with any other questions.

So it appears to be used as humorous slang, and you should only use it as such.

---

Edit: It's now been added to [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hangry?searchDictCode=all), which adds to its wordocrity.

Comment: never heard of it, but it does seem to exist [NGRAM](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hangry&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)

Comment: @mplungjan: Be careful with Ngrams. *Hangry* is an old spelling of *angry* and many may even be [OCR errors for *hungry*](http://books.google.com/books?id=B-ERAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA68&dq=%22hangry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=e8zBUPS0IamF4ATL8ICwDQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22hangry%22&f=false) or for effect. Picking at random from the Ngram: "A true hartist is never so 'appy as when he can have the advantage to gaze upon yonder tempestuous hocean in one of its hangry moods." ([1868](http://books.google.com/books?id=ktI8AAAAYAAJ&pg=PA53&dq=%22hangry%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=EMzBUKaAJo_Z4QSC5oFo&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA))

Comment: I know, but I saw more things that explained it well

Answer (score 2):

It is slang, but it's become commonly accepted slang...though not commonly used. According to the Urban Dictionary, it means:

> When you are so hungry that your lack of food causes you to become
>   angry, frustrated or both.
>
> An amalgum of hungry and angry invented to describe that feeling when
>   you get when you are out at a restaurant and have been waiting over an
>   hour to get the meal that you have ordered.

I found several other sites which used similar definitions...and in fact, it's the most logical definition I could think of.

Comment: I'd question the "not commonly used" caveat, it seems like I hear it daily recently.   It's a *portmanteau* word like "chortled," or "flustrated."

Comment: I'd question the "commonly accepted" caveat, it seems like I've never heard it outside of this post. It's a portmanteau word like "chortled," or "flustrated" which are usually restricted to Dr. Seuss and Lewis Carrol.